# ReactJs useState hook entering into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, use-state

My problem is, I want to do an async function, that executes when the user accesses a "page" it executes, gathers data from the database, and show it to the user, it works but into a never-ending loop. Here's the code:

```
  const [subbbed, setSubbed] = useState([])

  async function showSubscribed() {
    
        const response = await api.get('subscribed', {
               params: {
                   hour_id: person.id
               }
           })
    
        return response.data       
    }  
       
       useEffect(()=>{
        showSubscribed().then((data)=>{
            setSubbed(data)
        })
       })
```

And that "setSubbed(data)" is the one that generates the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing a second parameter to `useEffect`, so the callback to it will run on *every* render - so `showSubscribed` gets called on every render.

If you want `showSubscribed` to only run when the component is first mounted, pass an empty array as a second parameter:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    showSubscribed().then((data)=>{
      setSubbed(data)
    });
  },
  []
);
```

Similarly, if you want the `useEffect` callback to only run when a particular variable changes (for example, say you have a `pageNumber` variable in scope), you can put that variable into the array:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    showSubscribed().then((data)=>{
      setSubbed(data)
    });
  },
  [pageNumber]
);
```

This will result in `showSubscribed` being called

- on the first render, and later,
- whenever the `pageNumber` value changes

`useLayoutEffect` works the same way.

Comment: It worked, thanks, i was gettin crazy with this XD, i'm still new to reactJs